# How is shared library ASLR implemented in the Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I was able to easily locate code that ranzomizes "stack --> randomize_stack_top()" and "heap (brk) --> arch_randomize_brk()" in Linux kernel.

However, I do not see the code which randomizes the shared library start addresses. Can anyone point me to that code or make me see how the lib randomization is achieved (kernel source code)?

Comment: I believe the shared library shenanigans are fully done in userspace, i.e. it would be in `ld.so` (part of `glibc`).

Answer (score 1):

See this detailed post, this gives more pointers on code. This may change due to ever changing kernel. https://xorl.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/linux-kernel-aslr-implementation/